# Custom shop database structure

Tags: database, structure, e-commerce

I have my custom CMS system with simple shop module. Now I want to integrate new features as product variants, sizes and color. What's the best database structure for this? Now my product tables looks like:

```
products - product informations
products_lang - all product's strings for translation
products_categories - available categories
products_categories_pivot - pivot table for categories
products_similar_pivot - similar pivot table
```

I would like to solve issue when shop has for example running shoes model. What's the best approach? Create separate products for each shoes color? Or create table with colors of this product and then create more complicated queries to show all color variants in product list? And then what about shoes sizes? Each color can contain different sizes...

Answer (score 0):

In order to maintain normalization and value uniqueness, you should indeed create new tables for `Color` and `Size`.  You could link these to the products through an `Inventory` link table.

[image]

What I call value uniqueness is to ensure users do not create new color names or sizes that do not exist.

This does force you to `JOIN` tables through the `Inventory` table.  But it does allow you to easily produce reports like "how many blue shoes of size 9 do we have" or "what items need reordering since quantity = 0".